# how-to use dojo custom build

Tags: javascript, mobile, build, dojo

I'm developing a mobile app with `Dojo` and I'm using the Dojo toolkit SDK (about 30 MB)
For an HTML 5 mobile app it would be toooooo large to assemble it in an app package for Android, iOS or Windows Phone and hopefully after Binging and Googling for a solution to get only the "required" modules and I've found it on

> [build.dojotoolkit.org](http://build.dojotoolkit.org)

I uploaded my index.html single file to get automatically the 33 required packages and downloaded the generated custom build (about 500 KB) ...

The issue now is how can I use this custom build of Dojo
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to include Dojo.js (in the downloaded zip file) in your project that will contain all the Dojo modules you need, instead of using the CDN.

```
<script src="dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```